# regex lookahead assertion

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to python regex and am learning the lookahead assertion.

I found the following strange. Could someone tell me how it works?

```
import regex as re
re.search('(\d*)(?<=a)(\.)','1a.')
<regex.Match object; span=(2, 3), match='.'>

re.search('(\d+)(?<=a)(\.)','1a.')
out put nothing
```

Why doesn't the second one match anything?

Comment: The only difference here is `*` (0 or more occurrences) and `+` (1 or more occurrences) quantifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first pattern:

```
re.search('(\d*)(?<=a)(\.)', '1a.')
```

says to find zero or more digits, followed by a dot.  Right before the dot, it has a positive *lookbehind*, which asserts the previous character was an `a`.  In this case, Python will match zero digits, followed by a single dot.  The lookbehind fires true, because the preceding character was in fact an `a`.

However, the second pattern:

```
re.search('(\d+)(?<=a)(\.)','1a.')
```

matches *one* or more digits, followed the lookbehind and matching dot.  In this case, Python is compelled to match the number `1`.  But then it the lookbehind must fail.  Obviously, if the last character matched were a number, it cannot be the letter `a`.  So, there is no match possible in the second case.  Even if we were to remove `(?<=a)` from the second pattern, it would still fail because we are not accounting for the letter `a`.

Comment: i thought the matching principal was to test those patterns one by one. e.g. `1` matches `(\d+)`,`a` matches `(?<=a)` which is righter before the dot `.` as matched `(\.)`. so i thought the expression should return something: `.` or `1 .`(`(?<=a)` would not return values).

Comment: Now i think the reason may be that the expression cannot return `.` because it wants to return a `1` because of `(\d+)`  and it wants to return `.` at the same time because there is a `a` right before `.`, so the expression attemps `1 .` but it cannot do it because the `1` and `.` is not linked togther. so it returns nothing at all.

Comment: It matches a single number `1`, but then hits a lookbehind before the dot, insisting that an `a` came before it.  Obviously this fails, and to make matters worse there is an actual letter `a` there which is not matched to anything.

Comment: `re.search('(\d*)(?<=a)(\.)', '1a.')` this expression success because it can accept returned value as `.` because `(\d*)` is treated as zero digit.